# 投稿画面でformにログインユーザを既定したい

Tags: python, django

Djangoでブログ投稿アプリの制作をしています。
ログインユーザのアカウントに準じて投稿者を既定したいです。

その中でどのように定義してよいのか判らず困っております。
思い浮かぶ案
・HTMLでログインユーザを取得して、setするのか
・viewやformで定義すべきなのか

以下はHTML定義で、備考程度に査閲をお願いいたします

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Blog Create{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h2>ブログを投稿する</h2>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-11">
        <label for="id_title">タイトル</label>
        {{ form.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-11">
        <label for="id_text">本文</label>
        {{ form.text }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-11">
        <label for="id_category">カテゴリ</label>
        {{ form.category }}
    </div>
{# <div class="form-group col-md-11">#}
{#      <label for="id_author">著者</label>#}
{#      {{ form.author}}#}
{# </div>#}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">投稿</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htmlテンプレートにて{{ request.user.username }} は投稿者のアカウントです。
ユーザーのほかのattributeの値を参照したい場合、{{ request.user.attribute }}となります。

投稿formのauthorをログインしているユーザーのアカウントにしますかね。

```
<div class="form-group col-md-11">
<label for="id_author">著者</label>
 <input type="text" name="{{ form.author.name }}" id="{{ form.author.id_for_label }}" value="{{  request.user.username }}" >
</div>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます
上記の方法で実施してみたところ、ログインユーザを取得できたものの、投稿ボタンを押下しても投稿ができませんでした。
Devtoolからみるに、おそらく外部キーでカスタムユーザのUUIDを取得しなければならないように見えます。

Comment: htmlにて値があれば、問題がないと思います。投稿ボタンを押すと、このhtmlにてのform内容をデータベースに格納処理がうまくいかないようです。formをそのまま.saveではなくて、必要な処理を行ってからsaveを行う必要があると思います。

Comment: form.authorは外部キーでuserと繋がっていますかね。　　
そうすると、投稿formをsubmitすると、貴方のコードはわからないですが、以下のような処理が必要となります。　　
`username = request.POST['author'] #authorはhtmlにてform.authorのinputタグのname　　
form.author = user.objects.get(username=username)`

Comment: お世話になっております。
viewクラスにて以下を定義
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['user_pk'] = self.request.user.pk
            return context
テンプレートにて
    value="{{ user_pk }}"で取得することができました。

Answer (score 1):

「既定したい」という日本語はあまり聞いたことがありませんが、ログインユーザーを投稿者に設定したいということですかね？

[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates)を見ると、`{{ user.username }}`で取得できそうですが、どうでしょう？